# In Common-Lisp, how can I get a slice of a `grid:vector`?

Tags: vector, grid, common-lisp

In the manual of Antik, there're `grid:subgrid` and `grid:slice` for matrices, but I found nothing for vectors. And `grid:subgrid` `grid:slice` cannot be applied to vectors, there are errors.

#### Update

Now I have to use `(subseq (grid:copy-to vec 'array) 0 3` to do this, but it is just tricky...

Comment: I think I've given an answer to this, but without seeing what you're actually trying to do, and the actual error that you're getting from it, it's not possible to be sure.  At any rate, you _can_ use `grid:slice` with vectors (as shown in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### grid:slice with vectors

You can use `grid:slice` with vectors:

```
CL-USER> (grid:slice #(1 2 3 4 5) '((:range 0 2)))
;=> #(1.0 2.0 3.0)
```

From [the documentation for `grid:slice`](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/antik/antik/slice.html):

> — Function: **grid:slice** *grid index-selection &key destination drop*
>
> Select slice(s) from a grid. The index-selection is a list with length
>   equal to the rank of grid. Each element should be one of: an index,
>   indicating the index to be selected, :all, indicating the entire range
>   if indices are to be selected, :rev, indicating the entire range if
>   indices are to be selected in reverse order,
>
> *(:range start end stride)*, indicating a range of indices to be
>   selected; if stride is omitted, it is presumed to be 1,
>
> *(:select value …)*, indicating explicit values to be selected.

Based on that, since `#(1 2 3 4 5)` has rank 1, then index-selection needs to be a list of length one, and the single element is an list of the form `(:range start end [stride])`, in this case `(:range 0 2)`.

#### grid:subgrid with vectors

You can also use `grid:subgrid` on a vector:

```
CL-USER> (grid:subgrid #(1 2 3 4 5) '(3) '(2))
;=> #(3.0 4.0 5.0)
```

From [the documentation on `grid:subgrid`](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/antik/antik/subgrid.html):

> — Function: **grid:subgrid** *grid dimensions start &key destination drop*
>
> Create a grid from a block of an existing grid, e.g. a row from a
>   matrix, or a block. The dimensions give the dimensions of the subgrid,
>   and start gives the lowest values of each index which corresponds to
>   the subgrid element with all index values zero. If drop is true, all
>   singleton axes are dropped.

I'm not quite familiar with Antik's terminology, but it seems like, for the case of the vector, the *dimensions* argument is a list of how many elements you'll extract, and the *start* argument is a list of where to start.  My understanding here is based on some experimentation:

```
CL-USER> (grid:subgrid #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) '(3) '(2))
;=> #(3.0 4.0 5.0)
CL-USER> (grid:subgrid #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) '(3) '(4))
;=> #(5.0 6.0 7.0)
CL-USER> (grid:subgrid #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) '(2) '(5))
;=> #(6.0 7.0)
```

Comment: Do you mind my asking another question? How can I scale a slice or subgrid directly? Now I have to manually scale each element.

Comment: @SaltyEgg I haven't used Antik much, so I don't know whether I'll be able to help, but it sounds like a valid question, and a bunch of people will be taking a look if you post it (as its own question).  Do be sure to include what you've tried so far, though;  questions will get closed if they don't include your attempts.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Your interpretation of grid:subgrid is correct.

Comment: @SaltyEgg Not sure exactly what you mean by scaling a subgrid directly, but you should post another question with a clear statement of what you're trying to do.